# Maximize profit of a chemical plant

Tags: linear-programming, matlab, mathematical-modeling, word-problem, operations-research

> A chemical plant makes three major products on a weekly basis. Each of
>   these products requires a certain quantity of raw chemical and
>   different production times, and yields different profits. The
>   pertinent information is given in Table 1. Note that there is
>   sufficient warehouse space at the plant to store a total of
>   **450kg/week.**
>
> ```
>                 Product I   Product II    Product III   Resource Availability
> Raw Chemical       7kg          5kg           5kg              3000kg
> Production Time 0.05h/kg      0.1h/kg       0.2h/kg           55h/week
> Profit           $30/kg       $30/kg        $35/kg
> ```
>
> Table I: Datasheet of the three major products of the company.
>
> Set up a linear programming problem to maximize profit and solve it
>   using Simplex Method (manually), along with a graph and a MATLAB code
>   to solve the problem using Simplex Method (with comments) with an
>   algorithm/pseudocode for the same.

I recently started studying Linear Programming, and I don't know where to study from. I have tried checking several books, but I do not know how to approach such practical questions. I do not know how I should solve this question normally, and forming a Linear Programming Model, is tending to be too difficult for me. Also, I do not know how I should solve such questions using MATLAB, or any other mathematical software in general. Could anyone please help me out in this question?

I would appreciate a step-by-step solution, or some guidance in solving such practical questions in future. Also, could anyone recommend me a book for practical Linear Programming questions like these?

Comment: George Bernard Dantzig, [Linear Programming and Extensions](https://www.rand.org/pubs/reports/R366.html), RAND Corporation, 1963.

Comment: The first step is to translate words into linear inequalities.